# How to fix an Index Error in Python's Pandas Library

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, jupyter-notebook

I was setting up a statistical calculation, the code was previously working fine, possibly messed up by the new Pandas update.

I've tried to change the variables, still doesn't work.

```
drug1 = drug.loc[:, []].copy()
drug2 = drug1.dropna()
for i in ["DUQ200", "DUQ240", "DUQ250", "DUQ290", "DUQ330", "DUQ370", ]:
    print(drug2[i].value_counts()/drug2.count())
```

The expected result should have shown a very big or very small number, 
The actual result is:

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call
>   last) ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in
>   get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)    3077             try:
>   -> 3078                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)    3079             except KeyError:
>
> pandas_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()
>
> pandas_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()
>
> pandas_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in
>   pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()
>
> pandas_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in
>   pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()
>
> KeyError: 'DUQ240'
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in 
>         1 for i in [ "DUQ240", "DUQ250", "DUQ290", "DUQ330", "DUQ370", ]:
>   ----> 2     print(drug2[i].value_counts()/drug2.count())
>
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in
>   **getitem**(self, key)    2686             return self._getitem_multilevel(key)    2687         else:
>   -> 2688             return self._getitem_column(key)    2689     2690     def _getitem_column(self, key):
>
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in
>   _getitem_column(self, key)    2693         # get column    2694         if self.columns.is_unique:
>   -> 2695             return self._get_item_cache(key)    2696     2697         # duplicate columns & possible reduce dimensionality
>
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in
>   _get_item_cache(self, item)    2487         res = cache.get(item)    2488         if res is None:
>   -> 2489             values = self._data.get(item)    2490             res = self._box_item_values(item, values)    2491
>   cache[item] = res
>
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py in get(self,
>   item, fastpath)    4113     4114             if not isna(item):
>   -> 4115                 loc = self.items.get_loc(item)    4116             else:    4117                 indexer =
>   np.arange(len(self.items))[isna(self.items)]
>
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in
>   get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)    3078                 return
>   self._engine.get_loc(key)    3079             except KeyError:
>   -> 3080                 return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))    3081     3082
>   indexer = self.get_indexer([key], method=method, tolerance=tolerance)
>
> pandas_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()
>
> pandas_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()
>
> pandas_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in
>   pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()
>
> pandas_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in
>   pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()
>
> KeyError: 'DUQ240'

Comment: You data frame doesn't have a column named `'DUQ240'`. Actually `drug1 = drug.loc[:, []].copy()` -> `drug1` doesn't have any columns.

Comment: The data actually has a column named 'DUQ240' . When ever I removed it, it showed the same error for the other variables.

Comment: drug1 = drug.loc[:, []].copy() -> drug1 does not work, it is not a valid syntax

Comment: What I was trying to say is `drug1 = drug.loc[:, []].copy()` in your code gives an empty `drug1`.

Comment: Ok, this thing was working perfectly fine till this week.